# Questions about sequence $U_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}, \ n \geq 0.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The general term of a sequence is defined by $U_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} $ for all positive integers of n

a) Show that $U_{n+1}<U_n$ and that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=0$$

b) Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}$$

I don't understand any of this could someone please explain

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure about (b)?

Comment: You surely have made something. Show it.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{\color{red}{k}+1}-\sqrt{\color{red}{k}})=\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: a) What is the definition of $U_{n + 1}$? Well, $\sqrt{(n + 1) + 1} - \sqrt{n + 1}$. Hence, you have to prove that $\sqrt{(n + 1) + 1} - \sqrt{n + 1} < \sqrt{n + 1} -\sqrt{n}$. For the second part: What is here to understand? b) What is here to understand? Maybe, you cannot prove these, but you should understand everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a) we have to prove that $$\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}<\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$ this is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}<2\sqrt{n+1}$$
after squaring we get
$$\sqrt{n(n+2)}<n+1$$ and squaring again we get
$$0<1$$ which is true.
note that $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: I believe that you made a typo in the second line. $\ 2*\sqrt{n+1}$

Comment: yes indeed just corrected

Answer (score 6):

It's a standard trick, when one has $\sqrt{\mbox{junk}}-\sqrt{\mbox{stuff}}$ to multiply by its conjugate $\sqrt{\mbox{junk}}+\sqrt{\mbox{stuff}},$ which makes it just junk $-$ stuff.  To pay for this, you have to divide by the conjugate also, but that is often easier to deal with.

This trick will make part a) easy and will make the series in part b) telescoping.

Comment: [+1] I like your junky and stuffy argumentation.

Comment: Though the series telescopes even without the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can prove $U_{n+1} < U_n$ by induction, or by observation if you feel confident.

As for the limit, note that (by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}$)
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}) $$
This can be proved to be $0$ in a number of ways, which I'll leave to you (of course, feel free to ask questions), though if you're going to use the definition, it will help to note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}$

For the sum, expand out the nth partial sum and notice that telescoping occurs

Answer (score 0):

a) show $U_{n+1 } = \sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1} <U_n  = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$. I.e. show that $\frac12 (\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n}) < \sqrt{n+1}$. This is clear by the meanvalue theorem since the square root is a concave function.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{1+1/n}-1) < \lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n}/(2 n) = 0$
Since the result must be nonnegative, it is zero.

b) 
$\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}$ goes by telescoping. You have $\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=-1 + \sqrt{n+1} = \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n+1}}$

Answer (score 0):

a) We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}<\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$ or
$$\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n+2},$$ which is obvious.

b) Use a telescoping sum.